# Is my cherry tree dying?

Tags: fruit-trees, tree-care, cherries

I recently moved and there is a big cherry tree in the front garden.
Half of the branches are without leaves, with the bark peeling off. Most of the tree is covered with moss but there were definitely cherries on it a few months ago.

The "dead" branches are not dry, actually very flexible. Should I trim them? Or remove the whole tree?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd at least start with cutting off the parts with the bark peeling off.

I'd not get too hasty about taking the whole tree until seeing if that helped, particularly if it's bearing, and the cherries are any good.